# Fullcalendar onclick show dayview

Tags: onclick, fullcalendar, days

Im new to Javascript stuff especially on JSON and Jquery. I have successfully implement the monthly view of FullCalendar but is there anyway to show or pop up the dayview based on the date when user clicked on monthly view? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am guessing you want to switch to the day view when a user clicks on any day in the month view. If so, you can achieve this by using `dayClick` and `changeView` callbacks of FullCalendar.

Check this fiddle for a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/krJcL/

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer, still applicable.

Comment: just one thing, looks like the dayClick event changed slightly since then: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/  - dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {